# Lower bound on independence number in terms of clique number and order of graph

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics

In the paper "[On Multi-dimensional Packing Problems](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.104.6877&rep=rep1&type=pdf)" by Chekuri and Khanna there is the following lemma:

Lemma 4.3.(p. 191 of the paper) Let $G$ be a graph on $n$ vertices with $\omega(G) ≤ k$. Then $\alpha(G) ≥ n^{1/k}$.

If we substitute $G$ by a complete graph, then we get:
$\omega(G) = n$, then $\alpha(G) ≥ n^{1/n}>1$.

However, if I correctly understand the notion of an independence number, then $\alpha(K_n)=1,\forall n$. A contradiction to the lemma.

I have checked for several cases and it seems that this is the only one where the lemma doesn't hold.

Could someone explain what is wrong with my reasoning?

P.S. I sent this question to one of the authors before posting it here, but haven't received any answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where it says

```
then any maximal independent set has size at least $n^{1/k}$,
```

it should say

```
then any maximal independent set has size at least the floor of $n^{1/k}$,
```

(Then this sentence is true for the complete graph $K_k$.)

They are being a bit sloppy, but I imagine that they just need the result for "large enough $n$".

Comment: No problem! It was fun finding the "mistake" :) Just add "for large enough $n$" to the statement, and things are fine.

Comment: However, for large enough $n$ the lemma still doesn't hold for $K_k$.

Comment: @Oleksandr, for any fixed $k$, the statement of the lemma holds for large enough $n$.

Comment: Preciseness is a good explanation. You are right!